# What is this plant? 3/5 leaves per stem, thick trunk

Tags: identification, trees

[image: Unknown Plant]

Does anyone know what this is? I spontaneously grabbed it off the shelf at a flea market and now I don't know how to care for it!

Some stems have 5 leaves, and some have 3. The trunk is unique to what I've seen before.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like Pachira aquatica - this plant is often sold with plaited/braided stems, but yours has the more mature, bulbous trunk. Despite its name, this plant does not like wet soil - water when the surface of the soil in the pot feels just dry to the touch, water well and allow to drain freely, not leaving any water in an outer tray or pot. Prefers indirect bright light rather than direct sun - its a tropical plant so does not appreciate temperatures lower than 10 deg C. Images and info here https://www.ikea.cn/cn/en/catalog/products/10385163/